# Python | Decorators : calling function multiple time

Tags: python, python-decorators

Q.1 : When calling display second time why print('inside outer') is not called or why inside outer does't print?

Q.2 : We are just providing wrapper (function name) not actually calling it, then how does the wrapper function called, is it the decorator functionality that internally it calls the function when returned?

Code:

```
def outer(func):
    def wrapper():
        print('inside wrapper func')
        func()
    print('inside outer')
    return wapper

@outer
def display():
    print('inside display')
    
display()
display()

Output: 

inside outer
inside wrapper func
inside display
inside wrapper func
inside display
```

Comment: 1. Because `outer` itself is only called once, after that it's the `wrapper` (which then calls the original `display`) that gets called. 2. Yes, the `@` is just syntactic sugar for `display = outer(display)`.

Comment: Okay, Thanks a lot for quick response jonrsharpe@.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In functional programing,  what you just did is called side effect. A function is meant to return a value but you introduced a side effect by printing to the console!

Answering Q1, the outer function is called only once and that's immediately you do @outer. Even if you don't call display,  just decorating it will print 'inside outer'.  Try it!  So when you call display,  you're calling the wrapper function.

Answering Q2,  the pie syntax (@) is just a way of saying display = outer(display)
Now what it does is to print 'inside outer' and then returns the wrapper function.  So when you call display,  you aren't calling the outer function you're calling the wrapper. display is now like a pseudonym for wrapper.

Answer (score -1):

At Q2

> just providing wrapper (function name) not actually calling it, then how does the wrapper function called

It is just how python decorator works

---

At Q1

In decorator definition, we just call ONE command to get the decorator working

> return wrapper

When you need two commands

> print('inside outer')
> return wapper

My best guess is that the wrapper definition method load once only and for the 2nd time, it just reuse previous loaded compiled code